# Signing Up Parse User with Swift 1.2

Tags: parse-platform, swift

I use the signing up feature of Parse.com just as describe [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS). Here's my code:

```
 user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
      let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
      // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I've updated my project from swift 1.1 to swift 1.2 and get the following compiler error:

> Function signature '(Bool!, NSError!)->void is not compatible with
>   excepted type '@objc_block (Bool,NSError!)->Void'

it's on the following line:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

Does anybody know how can I fox that ? Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your succeeded variable is a 'Bool!' but what the block returns is a 'Bool' (without exclamation mark).

The solution would be:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
      let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
      // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    }
  }
}
```

Too see more about optionals [go to the apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with save in background with block. It looks like parse returns a "Bool not a Bool!"...however error is an NSError? unless you "!" it.

```
something.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

code
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: something.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in indeed ?